# Can admins migrate question that are old?

Tags: support, migration

If an question is very old, but very misplaced on Stack Overflow -- can an admin migrate that question the request of the question's author?

Or, are admin-limits to migration the same as user limits?

Comment: I agree there are tons of very good questions (with many votes) that do not belong to SO. I.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649006/can-i-have-multiple-dkim-txt-records-in-single-domain should belong to serverfault, it has got nothing to do at all with programming-

Answer (score 4):

It is technically possible, but it is only done in *very* specific situations, such as when the question is of *particularly* high value, and also where the question is, or is about to be, deleted on the site it is currently on, and it is a difficult process that even moderators cannot do.

If you simply see an okay question that's not at risk of being deleted that you think ought to be migrated, but it's too old, you should not try to request its migration, the request is just going to be denied.

Comment: There are just a ton questions that are db-specific that remain on StackOverflow. Questions that should have been migrated a very long time ago to [dba.se] and that have nothing to do with a programming task. Some of them are my own questions.

Comment: @EvanCarroll See my second paragraph.

Comment: To clarify: Moderators cannot bypass the age restriction for migration, only staff can. And we rarely will use that power. We also would *never* migrate an old question to a brand new site in today's time.

Comment: @TinyGiant There's a reason the 90 day limit was put in place.  It's not just arbitrary.   Migrating old questions causes lots of problems, which is why it is no longer done.  Feel free to look up the discussion on why the limit was put in place to begin with if you want know more.  If there were actually no reason not to migrate any good old question then the limit wouldn't be there in the first place.  (If you feel it's not longer merited, then feel free to propose it's removal, but flagging content that policy dictates shouldn't be moved is just wasting people's time.)

Comment: @animuson The question specifically called out administrators, and acknowledged that moderators couldn't do it, hence why I didn't bother to re-clarify the point.  If there's a better example of what the exceptions might be, I'm more than happy to correct that portion.

Comment: The exception is an outstanding question with amazing content that the current site wants deleted but would make a great question somewhere else. That's pretty much it. (Also, the question doesn't seem to mention moderators, just "admins" and "users", which is why I clarified.)

Comment: @animuson How's that look?

Comment: @TinyGiant You shouldn't ever flag it. If someone truly believes a question is of that great quality that it should be migrated after the 60 days is up, they should probably be posting on Meta about it. ;)

Comment: @animuson did I slip and say flag in my now-deleted comment? I was trying to stick to "request".

Comment: @animuson in Evan's history from MSO and MSE, he usually refers to moderators as "admins".

Comment: I'm curious what the reasoning is for that @animuson? I don't really see any downsides to migrating old "good" (but not "amazing") questions to e.g. Super User? What am I missing?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker The justification I remember hearing was always that new sites need to establish themselves independently with their new community's direct involvement, not by being "seeded" with a bunch of old questions (aka baggage) from previous sites. Vote skew is another problem. An old question on SO that is good enough to migrate will likely have an *astronomical* amount of votes, relative to what you'd expect to see on another SE site. Migration retains votes, so this creates some problems. See also [the original feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/).